# ajax call/response, appended value to autocomplete is adding but not filtering

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using javascript with an ajax call/response in order to query an endpoint and return part of the results to a datalist in my form input.

This is working (meaning, my returned result is populating the datalist) but my problem is filtering the items.

Say I'm searching for 'Box' in the input. Typing the 'B' returns 13 items and they show properly in the datalist. When I add the typed 'o' ('Bo' is now in the input) then I return only 7 items in the new call/return in my console. However, my datalist shows all 20 items, where it should only show the newest 7 items, especially if some exist in the previous 13.

What am I doing wrong here that's causing this not to filter, or only show the latest results per keystroke?

```
<input id ="productInput"  class="uk-search-field" type="search" placeholder="search products..." list="returnedProducts">
   <datalist id="returnedProducts">

    </datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">

//input event handler
$('#productInput').on('input', function(){
    if($(this).val() === ''){
       return;
    }else{

       //input value
       const searchResult = $(this).val(); 

       $.ajax({ url: '/autocomplete', 
                data: {
                    search_result:searchResult
                },
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                type: "POST", 
                success: function(response){
                    let searchResult = response.hits.hits;
                    for(let i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {

                        $("#returnedProducts").append("<option value=" + searchResult[i]._source.category + ">" + searchResult[i]._source.category + "</option>");
                        console.log(searchResult[i]._source);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are appending suggestions but you never clean the previous suggestions. Starting the `success` callback with `$('#returnedProducts').empty();` should do the trick ([link to .empty() doc](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)).

Comment: Yup, that did it! That was way less of a headache than I expected, thank you!

Comment: Cheers mate! :)